# How to use chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/ in windows CMD command line

Tags: error, command-line

[image]

### 'chmod' is not recognized as an internal or external command

---

I am trying to use this command on windows cmd for Magento permissions but this not working can anyone tell me how to use this command on windows and where to use this is if my Magento Home page is not loading

Comment: No need to permission for windows. Can you add screenshot of homepage and console error as well?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the problem that I am having

Comment: No, I need to see screenshot of homepage where you facing issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are following something in the wrong guide as chmod is a command in Unix i.e Unix based operating systems like Linux that is used to change the access permissions of files and directories.

So what you can do:

- Change permissions with right click on folder and change permissions.
- Use any tool to change the permission of the folder

Have look into it: https://narmadanannaka.com/how-to-run-the-chmod400-command-on-windows as an alternative.